# Number of degree d curves passing through d points in the projective plane over a finite field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, enumerative-geometry

Let the base field be a finite field $\mathbb F_q$ and fix $d$ rational points that lie on a line in $\mathbb P^2$. Suppose $d$ is a large number (about the order of $q^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha$ some positive real number). Are there good estimates on the number of degree $d$ curves that pass through these fixed $d$ points?

I would be happy assuming the curves are irreducible if that makes the problem simpler (but I don't except this assumption to change the asymptotics anyway).

More generally, suppose we fix $r$ points but keep the same degree. Then how many curves of degree $d$ pass through $r$ points? I only mostly care about asymptotics.

Comment: Are your points rational over $\mathbb{F}_q$? If not, then I guess you want to assume that your set of points is stable under Galois.

Comment: Yes, I am okay with assuming they are rational.

Comment: The space of plane curves of degree $d$ is a projective space, and passing through $r$ points gives you linear conditions on the coefficients of the equation, so what you get is a linear subspace, which has codimension $r$ if the points are in generic position. But maybe you also want to have control in every case?

Comment: Right, that would be ideal. Also, why does genericity imply the right codimension?

Comment: I forgot that your $r$ points are rational, so there are only finitely many possibilities for them and genericity doesn't make much sense. I was thinking geometrically (say over the algebraic closure). So the number of curves will depend on the position of these points; which number do you want to estimate? You have $r$ equations, so the codimension is at most $r$, but can be less e.g. if your points satisfy collinearity conditions. For conics ($5$-dim parameter space) passing through 5 points, "generic" means "no 4 points collinear", but in general I don't know.

Comment: Right, but I think the fact that the nine of points is smaller than the dimension of the space of curves should make it so that it doesn't really matter which number I care about. I am not sure...

Comment: Nine = number...

Comment: In fact, I think I would like to assume that the points all line on a line. So as far from generic as possible.

Comment: I see, then the restriction of the defining polynomial to that line will be completely determined (its roots will correspond to the points you took), then you can add any multiple of the equation of the line. So the dimension of your linear subspace will be the dimension of the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d-1$. So I think you have codim $d$ in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Let me think about it a little.